# Move location of google maps pin in link?

Tags: google-maps

Ive created a link to a google maps page. The pin appears to be in the correct place until I go to street view, and then the view is 1 door down from where it should be. How can I move the pin so its in the correct place in the link?

Ive tried entering different addresses but I cant get it to show the right place, so I think I need to move it manually. If I choose the 'move marker' option it tries to change the location for that address, but I dont actually need this and my changes dont seem to have been applied anyway.

Thanks